# What is the difference between "anchor to character" and "anchor as character" in openoffice writer?

Tags: openoffice-writer

OpenOffice Writer (swriter.exe) has several options for anchoring a graphics object in the document including *anchor to page*, *anchor to paragraph*, *anchor to character* and *anchor as character*. What is the difference between the last two? I did not figure it out as no apparent difference seemed to be visible after applying either of the two.

Answer (score 3):

#### What is the difference between "anchor *to* character" and "anchor *as* character"

> **To Character**
>
> - The graphic is associated with a character but is not in the text sequence.
> - It moves with the paragraph but may be placed in the margin or another location.
> - This method is similar to anchoring to a paragraph but cannot be used with drawing objects.
>
> **As Character**
>
> - The graphic is placed in the document like any other character and, therefore, affects the height of the text line and the line break.
> - The graphic moves with the paragraph as you add or delete text before the paragraph.
> - This method is useful for keeping screenshots in sequence in a procedure (by anchoring them as a character in a blank paragraph) or
>     for adding a small (inline) icon in sequence in a sentence.

Source [Arranging, anchoring, and aligning](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Arranging_anchoring_aligning)